# What CSS element is making this text so small?

Tags: css

If you go here - http://www.joecrabtree.com/store -  and add a product to the cart, all the text in the cart is way smaller than everything else.

I've played around in the element inspector in Chrome and I can't find anything I can change that will make the cart text larger WITHOUT affecting the rest of the text on the page.

That is, I don't understand what's making it smaller than everything else.

Comment: This question becomes entirely useless if your site goes down some day and is terribly inconvenient as it stands. Please edit the relevant HTML/CSS into your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the enclosing `<td>` tag contains the following style:

```
media="all"
body, caption, th, td, input, textarea, select, option, legend, fieldset {
    font: 0.75em/1.6em Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

From line 34 of style.css. I see you have similar specifications for nested parents of the table cell. These can have an accumulative effect.

Might I suggestion you specify font sizes in points or pixels?

Comment: Thank you! Nesting and accumulation was outside my radar.  I wish I'd asked before spending countless hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**styles.css line 34**:

```
body, caption, th, td, input, textarea, select, option, legend, fieldset {
    font: 0.75em/1.6em Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`em` font sizes are relative to the current size..

When you nest elements that have `font-size` different to 1 then you get progressively larger or smaller fonts the deeper in the nesting you go..

example http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/NcKNF/

You code has `0.75em` font size for the `td` elements and even higher the DOM you have `#cart-block-contents-ajax` with `0.9em` font size. and on and on ..

you current structure is

```
#page   0.83em  
    .sidebar   0.95em  
        #ajaxCartUpdate   0.95em  
            #cart-block-contents-ajax   0.9em
                td   0.75em
```

so it gets smaller the deeper you go in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be cascading font-sizes of less than 1em:

From Firebug:

```
#cart-block-contents-ajax   0.9em   style.css?H (line 870)

#page   font-size: 0.83em   style.css?H (line 30)

.sidebar    font-size: 0.95em   style.css?H (line 297)

body    font-size: 100% layout.css?H (line 149)

body    font-size: 0.75em   style.css?H (line 34)

td          font-size: 0.75em   style.css?H (line 34)
```

So the `body` is set to `100%`, then it is reset to `0.75em`, then `.83em` (#page), then `.95em` (.sidebar), then `.75em` (td) and finally `.9em` (#cart-block-contents-ajax)

So that's .9 of .75 of .95 of .83 of .75 of 100% = .399 em

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your css, and it will override any other css that is causing your font to be small.. This will only affect what is in your cart.

```
/*cart item */
.block .content #cart-block-contents-ajax .cart-block-items tbody .odd {font-size:15px;}

/* remove product links */
.block .content #cart-block-contents-ajax .cart-block-items tbody .cart-block-item-desc {font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;}

/* Total Items */
.cart-block-summary-items,.cart-block-summary-total {font-size:15px; padding:5px}

/* View cart and Checkout links */
.cart-block-summary-links .links {font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;}
```

Hope this helps.

and to answer your question: this attribute added to the `body` is what is making your font small:

`font: 0.75em/1.6em Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`